# download_as_text from Google Cloud Storage Blob / Object causes UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, character-encoding, google-cloud-storage, decode

I am trying to obtain human-readable text from a PDF stored as a [Cloud Storage Blob / Object](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html). The documentation tells me that the `download_as_string()` method is deprecated in favor of using `download_as_bytes()` to download the contents of the blob as a bytes object.

```
json_string = blob_list[0].download_as_bytes() 
print(json_string)
```

When I run the above code the content of the blob is downloaded as a bytes object, but this is not human-readable and not what I am looking for.

[image: bytes object of]

Next I tried to use both `download_as_text()` and `download_as_text().decode()` however both of those methods threw the following error:  `return data.decode("utf-8") UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 10: invalid continuation byte`

[image: download_as_text]

My last attempt was to use `download_as_bytes().decode('ISO-8859-1')` which does not cause an error, but does not return human-readable text.

[image: ISO-8859-1 encoding]

What am I doing wrong?  How do I obtain text from the Cloud Storage Blob / Object?

Comment: As I continue my research into this issue, I have now learned that PDFs are made of binary data, not text.  This means they cannot meaningfully be represented as Unicode strings.  I think the answer will be to use Google Cloud Vision API and `vision.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` to get the text of the PDF.

Comment: There are many libraries that can read and parse PDFs.

Comment: I chose the Cloud Vision API more or less at random. Is there any particular reason to use one over another?

Comment: Cloud Vision is overkill to read a PDF. PDFs have a structured format that programs can read/process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDF files are made of binary data rather than text. This means they can't be expressed as Unicode strings in any meaningful way.
The Google Cloud Vision API and [`vision.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Feature) can be used to [get the text](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/fulltext-annotations) from PDFs.
To read a PDF, Cloud Vision is overkill.

Programs can read and process PDFs because they have a structured format. There are also numerous libraries that can read and interpret PDF files.